# check if all elements with similar IDs are selected using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to check if all buttons starting with id `approve-` are selected. Buttons are dynamically created and number of buttons are not constant.

```
<button type="button" id="approve-<?php echo $item->getId();?>">Approve</button>

<button type="button" id="reject-<?php echo $item->getId();?>">Reject</button>
```

I know about a function `$j("button[id^='approve-']"` but following code alerts "All Selected" even if one of the button is clicked.

```
if($j("button[id^='approve-']")){
        alert("All Clicked");
      }
```

Comment: By _selected_ do you mean _clicked_?

Comment: Yes, I've updated question too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the attribute for which button is clicked ,then check approve button length with clicked approve button length

```
$(document).on('click', 'button', function () {
    $(this).attr('clicked', true);
    if ($("button[id^='approve-']").length == $("button[id^='approve-'][clicked]").length) {
        alert("all approved clicked")
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4pounzvg/)**